# What is the meaning of "grief could be borne one day, one chore, at a time"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Rose, who spoke for the first time about her own lost children, had
> showed Elsa that grief could be borne one day, one chore, at a time.

I know the meaning of the words separetly but I don't understand the meaning of the sentence.

I think it means:

*Grief could be borne once - **like** one chore - **one by one**.*

but I am not sure that I am right.

So could you please explain it to me?

The fuller text is here:

> When Elsa had lost her third child—a son who never drew breath—it was
> Rose who held Elsa and let her cry, and said, Some lives are not ours
> to hold on to; God makes His choices without us. Rose, who spoke for
> the first time about her own lost children, had showed Elsa that **grief
> could be borne one day, one chore, at a time**.

*The Four Winds* by kristin Hannah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we should understand the meaning of "borne". To "bear" something literally means that it is carried, although it is heavy.  You cope with the heavy weight.

To "bear grief" is the cope with the sadness, figuratively.

Now how do you cope with sadness?  Rose shows Elsa that she copes with sadness "one day at a time" This means that deals with the grief she feels at the present, and doesn't worry about the future.

She also deals with it "one chore at a time". This suggests that she copes with grief by doing housework, and doing one chore, then another, then another...

The overall impression is of a woman who copes with grief by keeping busy, so she doesn't have time to think too much about the thing that makes her sad.